# Positively match polar questions in part-of-speech tagged text

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this type of part-of-speech tagged utterances in column `c7`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  c7 = c("um_UH I_PPIS1 was_VBDZ there_RL",
         "that_DD1 's_VBZ me_PPIO1",
         "when_RRQ was_VBDZ that_DD1",
         "holy_JJ shit_NN1 does_VDZ it_PPH1 happen_VVI",
         "what_DDQ kind_NN1 of_IO pants_NN2 is_VBZ that_DD1",
         "are_VBR the_AT pictures_NN2 nice_JJ",
         "does_VDZ n't_XX it_PPH1",
         "no_UH you_PPY did_VDD n't_XX"))
```

I want to match polar (or 'yes'/'no') questions. One condition, among others, for polar questions is that the verbs are **not** preceded (at some distance) by question words ('who', 'what', etc.) or personal pronouns ('I', 'you', etc.) or demonstratives ('that'). I find myself unable to **exclude** utterances that do not match this negative condition by using negative lookbehind. The only way I can exclude them is by matching them in the pattern with **positive lookbehind** and by using `grep`'s argument `invert = TRUE`:

```
# pattern:
p1 <- "(?<=Q|_D|_P)(\\w{2,4})?\\s(['\\w]+\\s){0,3}['\\w]+_V(B|D|H).{1,2}\\s(n't_XX\\s)?(there|.{2,4}_(P|D))?"

# matching:
grep(p1, df$c7, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
[1] "holy_JJ shit_NN1 does_VDZ it_PPH1 happen_VVI" "are_VBR the_AT pictures_NN2 nice_JJ"         
[3] "does_VDZ n't_XX it_PPH1"
```

Is there a way to **positively** match polar questions? That is, is there an alternative way to assert that the verbs must not be preceded by questions words (part-of-speech tags ending in `Q`, pronouns (tags starting with `P`), demonstratives (tags starting with `D`) etc.?

Comment: Can you split each value by whitespace, then split those by underscore to make a data frame that's easier to work with?

Comment: @camille Yes: `df$c7x <- lapply(lapply(df$c7, function(x) unlist(str_extract_all(x, "([A-Z]+)"))), paste0, collapse = " ")`

Comment: Are you trying to extract just token-POS pairs that match the condition, or the full line of text where that condition is true for all token-POS pairs? If the latter, am I reading it correctly that only row 6 matches fully?

Comment: I want to match the full line of text. Rows 4, 6, and  7 should match.

Answer (score 3):

This was an interesting task. Rather than try to do everything in one regex pattern, I treated the tokens and part of speech tags as their own types of information, and reshaped the data frame to have one token-tag pair per row.

In production, you might not store all these logical conditions as their own columns, but it helps make the logic more clear. The checks I'm using are:

- if a tag matches the verb pattern, it's a verb
- if a tag matches the question pattern, it signals a question
- if any previous question words have been found for that line of text (ID), there's a previous question word
- if a token is both a verb and preceded by a question term, it's polar (not sure if that's the terminology)

Once you've filtered out lines that had any polar flags, collapse the text back into a single line per ID.

```r
library(dplyr)

quest_patt <- "(Q$|^P|^D)"
verb_patt <- "^V[DBH]"

df_out <- df %>%
  tibble::rowid_to_column("id") %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(c7, sep = "\\s") %>%
  tidyr::separate(c7, into = c("token", "tag"), sep = "_", remove = FALSE) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(is_verb = grepl(verb_patt, tag),
         is_question = grepl(quest_patt, tag),
         prev_question = cumsum(is_question) > 0,
         is_polar = is_verb & prev_question) %>%
  filter(!any(is_polar))
df_out
#> # A tibble: 12 × 8
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>       id c7           token    tag   is_verb is_question prev_question is_polar
#>    <int> <chr>        <chr>    <chr> <lgl>   <lgl>       <lgl>         <lgl>   
#>  1     4 holy_JJ      holy     JJ    FALSE   FALSE       FALSE         FALSE   
#>  2     4 shit_NN1     shit     NN1   FALSE   FALSE       FALSE         FALSE   
#>  3     4 does_VDZ     does     VDZ   TRUE    FALSE       FALSE         FALSE   
#>  4     4 it_PPH1      it       PPH1  FALSE   TRUE        TRUE          FALSE   
#>  5     4 happen_VVI   happen   VVI   FALSE   FALSE       TRUE          FALSE   
#>  6     6 are_VBR      are      VBR   TRUE    FALSE       FALSE         FALSE   
#>  7     6 the_AT       the      AT    FALSE   FALSE       FALSE         FALSE   
#>  8     6 pictures_NN2 pictures NN2   FALSE   FALSE       FALSE         FALSE   
#>  9     6 nice_JJ      nice     JJ    FALSE   FALSE       FALSE         FALSE   
#> 10     7 does_VDZ     does     VDZ   TRUE    FALSE       FALSE         FALSE   
#> 11     7 n't_XX       n't      XX    FALSE   FALSE       FALSE         FALSE   
#> 12     7 it_PPH1      it       PPH1  FALSE   TRUE        TRUE          FALSE

df_out %>%
  summarise(c7 = paste(c7, collapse = " "))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>      id c7                                          
#>   <int> <chr>                                       
#> 1     4 holy_JJ shit_NN1 does_VDZ it_PPH1 happen_VVI
#> 2     6 are_VBR the_AT pictures_NN2 nice_JJ         
#> 3     7 does_VDZ n't_XX it_PPH1
```

Comment: I definitely agree. Performing a few simple tests makes it easy to understand what you want to do. This makes the code more readable.

Comment: That's pretty cool! Thanks a million, indeed! Just so I understand what's wrong with the positive lookbehind: can you tell me why it's not working? That is, why is `p1 <- "(?<!Q|_D|_P)... and all the rest of the pattern"` not doing the job of excluding tokens where there are question words, demonstrtives, and pronouns prior to the verb??

Comment: Your solution too is ex negativo. You define all the non-polar question parameters bit by bit only to filter these out with `filter(!any(is_polar))`. The problem with this negative filtering is that the toy data presented in the question just contains a handful of mostly question-type/question-like data. In the actual data set, by contrast, there are millions of utterances that are far from being anywhere near any question type and that would still be classified as polar question just because they do not have the non-polar characteristics!

Comment: I don't really get what you mean, since the only data I had to build from is the example you gave. Is there some distance between the question term and the verb that would make it no longer count as being near each other?